# .htaccess deny access to file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wrote the follow .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>

<Files "indexbig.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

I want to deny access to the file "indexbig.php" but only allow acces from the local server. Somehow this allows access to every host. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I would expect this to be doing the opposite of what you're saying since you're checking for allow first and then basically negating it by then denying from all. Have you tried changing to `Order deny, allow`?

Comment: @abney317 Switching order stills allows every host to access indexbix.php

Comment: If you remove the `Allow from 127.0.0.1` line it then denies everyone?